# Dynamically populate an ng-container based on a list of ng-template that are TemplateRef in component.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, components

To further explain, I want to populate an ng-container based on a list of ng-templates. Each ng-template is added one after the other. In other words ng-template contains two buttons previous and next. previous removes current ng-template and returns the previous template. Next button removes the current ng-template and adds the next ng-template.

My issue is referencing each template using TemplateRef in component.ts. I tried getting each template reference from the component.ts constructor but this doesn't work. My code below explains the approach I used.

**home.component.html**

```html
    <div class="template-container">
      <!-- Ng Container -->
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="activeTemplate">
      </ng-container>
    
        <!-- Select Service -->
        <ng-template #allServices>
           <!-- TODO -->
        </ng-template>
    
      <!-- Select Worker -->
      <ng-template #worker>
        <!-- TODO -->
      </ng-template>
    
      <!-- Display Calendar -->
      <ng-template #calendar>
        <!-- TODO -->
      </ng-template>
    
      <!-- User entails user details -->
      <ng-template #userDetails>
        <!-- TODO -->
      </ng-template>
    </div>
```

**home.component.ts**

```js
    import { Component, VERSION, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.full;
      
      templates: TemplateRef<any>[] = [];
      activeTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
      
      constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {
        this.templates = [
          this.templateRef.allServices, // Error occurs
          this.templateRef.worker, // Error occurs
          this.templateRef.calendar, // Error occurs
          this.templateRef.userDetails // Error occurs
        ];
        this.activeTemplate = this.templates[0];
      }
      
    }
```

You can see how I am trying to pull out each reference but this does not work. I should also say I am very new to Angular and I read the documentation for `TemplateRef` from angular and to my understanding `ElementRef` is supposed to be the reference of the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inject in constructor templateRef this is about your component home.component. You need get the templates using ViewChild

```
ViewChild('allServices',{static:true}) template0:TemplateRef<any>
ViewChild('worker',{static:true}) template1:TemplateRef<any>
ViewChild('calendar',{static:true}) template2:TemplateRef<any>
ViewChild('userDetails',{static:true}) template3:TemplateRef<any>
```

And use

```
index=0;
this.activeTemplate = this['template'+index];
```

butyou asign the variable activeTemplate in `ngOnInit` (or in ngAfterViewInit if you don't use `{static:true}`) **not** in constructor

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rbrxy4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)